# React Jest how to test an external async await function being called?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs, enzyme

I have an react hook component and onClick event, when I trigger the event I would call an async function from other file/module, how could I test this method being called with Jest since this method is not passing through prop but from external resource, for example

```
import {someAsyncFn} from '../../../externalFile';
--My component on click method
const onClick = async (userId) => {
    await someAsyncFn(userId);
};
```

I tried to use jest.fn or jest.spy in my test but that doesn't seem to work..

```
import * as externalMod from '../../../externalFile';
it('someAsyncFn should called', async() => {
   const spy = spy(externalMod, 'someAsyncFn');
   ...simulate('click');
   await expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks):

```
import {someAsyncFn} from '../../../externalFile';

jest.mock('../../../externalFile');

it('someAsyncFn should called', async() => {
   someAsyncFn.mockResolvedValue(someDataToMock);
   ...simulate('click');
   expect(someAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: I am a little confused, what's the usage of jest.mock of my external file while the actual method was imported already?

Comment: I've tried this, yes my `someAsyncFn` was being called, however it seems it never gets resolved, I have some other method after `someAsyncFn` are not being called that may be blocked by `someAsyncFn`, do you have any suggestion how to resolve that?

Comment: I've figured it out, seems I need to add `await Promise.resolve();` after the `expect(someAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalled();` and it'll work

Comment: answer to your first question: it's how `jest` works internally. It parses your file, find `jest.mock` and processes it _before_ parsing everything else(so `import` also comes next). That's why we mock and import and everything works well.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, seems like using the mock, my function is like `fake` one...so I'm expecting my function to be called with userId 1, but even I test it to have been called with userid 3 or even on parameter, test case also passed... does it mean after mock, all method inside my file are not `real`?

Comment: @KevDing I don't understand your question. Not "some functions are like fake" but only when you mock a module where they are declared. Also you may provide any [return value for mocked function to return](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) if you need that.

Comment: Hi what I mean is when I pass my userId of 1 in my test case, and I am expecting ```expect(someAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)```, which passed the test case, but if I do ```expect(someAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)``` or ```expect(someAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(999)``` the test also passed, so I am not sure whether my ```someAsyncFn``` was really called with correct parameter here,

Comment: The ```someDataToMock``` in your example would be the result data that to mock when the ```someAsyncFn``` resolved, right?

Comment: also I tried someOtherAsyncFn in my mocked file that should not be called during my simulate click event, like ```expect(someOtherAsyncFn).toHaveBeenCalled();``` it also passed the test... Which makes me confused, after ```mock``` the file, my ```someAsyncFn ``` is not the original ```someAsyncFn``` from my file...

Comment: that does not make any sense for `.toHaveBeenCalledWith` to pass always. Create different question with full test case's code. My wild guess you are having async code but  not letting Jest know about that, so test case finishes without that check for `.toHaveBennCalled()` assertion.